# how to pass arguments to linux at command

Tags: php, linux, shell

I need to run a mail.php file later instead of keeping the user to wait for the validation email to be sent when they submit for register.php.

So I chose to use the **at** command to run mail.php ( **invoked in register.php** ) in command line 1 minute later:

But I can only send parameters to that php file when I was on the interactive mode of the at command.

```
at now + 1 minute
at> php mail.php {email}     # {email} is the argument I want to pass
```

Since I want this be automatic, so I need to use at run a shell script:

```
at -f mail.sh
```

But I could't find a proper way to pass the **{email}** argument,

**I tried** to set an environment varaible in Shell but also in vain:

In the **register.php** file, I wrote:

```
shell_exec('export email=foo@bar.com');
shell_exec('at -f mail.sh now + 1 minute');
```

In the **mail.sh**, I wrote:

```
#! /bin/bash
php mail.php $email
```

Comment: Why is mail.php blocking to such an extent you're concerned about making the user wait while it executes?

Comment: May be due to some routing issue or some network bandwidth on my server that I haven't looked into yet. By the way, I use the PHPMailer in mail.php.

Comment: IIRC PHPMailer submits mail to an SMTP server for queueing and dispatch. So it shouldn't be blocking at all. It would be far better to implement asynchronous e-mailing than to start using the system shell from your web application, as there are always security issues permitting shell access.

Comment: Any idea on how to implement asynchronous e-mailing? @deed02392

Comment: I'm just saying I thought that was how phpmailer worked. I submit an e-mail to my local SMTP server to mail which takes ms. Are you trying to connect to the target mailserver directly and send the mail that way, ie implementing an SMTP client in PHP?

Comment: No, I didn't implement a SMTP server myself. I use Gmail do it for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read commands from stdin rather than from a file. (bash's) here-doc syntax works nice here:

```
shell_exec('at now + 1 minute <<EOF
    php mail.php test@test.com
EOF
');
```

Comment: Additional note: `now + 1 minute` doesn't execute the command 60 seconds later. It will execute the command on the next *full minute* meaning HH:MM:00.. This can be just a second delay if you execute the command at HH:MM:59

Comment: Weird, it always prompts this syntax error. Last token seen : + . Garbled time

Comment: Yeah, it works. I forgot the here-doc format, thought it goes into bash and has nothing to do with PHP, so I didn't format here-doc right. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can use this:

```
shell_exec('echo php mail.php test@test.com | at now + 1 minute');
```

Answer (score 0):

in one go: `shell_exec('export email=foo@bar.com; at -f mail.sh now + 1 minute');`

or just: `shell_exec('php mail.php foo@bar.com');`

Comment: ... or how does the second cmd uses `at` to delay the cmd?

Answer (score 0):

1) For Linux. Check file

/etc/at.deny

Remove user "www-data" if exist.

2) Schedule simple command with php.

Linux

```
exec('echo "mkdir /tmp/testAT" | at now + 1 minute');
```

Windows

```
exec('at "16:45:01 20.09.2017" cmd /c mkdir C:\Server\_debug\1\testAT');
```

3) Schedule Symfony framework command.

```
exec('echo "php /var/www/mysite.com/app/console system:test_command param1 param2 --env=test" | at 11:14 AM 19.09.17');
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the original question has been satisfactorily answered, but if you are using `popen` in your PHP script to perform the **at** command, you can include arguments (as GET parameters) like this:

```
$target_script_path = "path/to/your/target/script";
$time = "now";
$file = popen("/usr/bin/at $time", "w");
//$cmd = "/usr/bin/php $target_script_path"; // Working example with no arguments supplied.
//$cmd = "/usr/bin/php $target_script_path?test_param=test_value"; // Trying to use a GET parameter like this does not work!
$cmd = "/usr/bin/php $target_script_path test_param=test_value"; // Working example *with* argument!
fwrite($file, $cmd);
pclose($file);
```

Then you can pick up the `test_param` value in your target script with:

```
$test_param = $_GET['test_param']; // "test_value"
```