# job scheduling with at not working with php

Tags: php, command, job-scheduling

I am trying to execute at command in php but it is not working..suppose I wanted to execute a php script after 10 minutes, so the code I wrote for it..

```
ob_start();
system('echo curl http://www.domain.com/timetest.php | at now + 10 min 2>&1', $returnVal);
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

but this command working good from console like..

```
echo curl http://www.domain.com/timetest.php | at now + 10 min
```

if I execute following command it works from console as well as php but it execute the script immediately...

```
system('curl http://www.domain.com/timetest.php | at now + 10 min 2>&1', $returnVal);
```

I also have tried some more format by googling..like..

```
system('echo "curl http://www.domain.com/timetest.php" | at now + 10 min 2>&1', $returnVal);
```

Someone plz help me in getting it right.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
system('echo "curl http://...." | at now + 10 minutes', $retval);
```

You can also use bash's here-doc syntax:

```
system('at now + 10 minutes <<EOF
    curl "http://..."
EOF
', $retval);
```

Comment: first one I tried again but not working and second one is giving error.."syntax error. Last token seen: c Garbled time"

Comment: what if you try `shell_exec()` like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980131/how-to-pass-arguments-to-linux-at-command/19980407#19980407 ?

Comment: What means `not working` ? You see I have tested it (and the opener of the other question too)

Comment: No, just text, but the newlines are important. However, the first approach (echo) should work as well.. You say it is not working. What means this? Btw, are you using Linux or Windows?

Comment: I am using linux server...and when I run this command using SSH client...
echo curl http://.... | at now + 10 min , It works fine

Comment: are you sure that there are no windows line endings in your source code?

Comment: The code I have written in windows but it is running on linux

Comment: make sure that you are using linux line endings in your editor

Comment: when I am running command system('echo "curl..." | at now + 2 min 2>&1') it is giving output like "job 68 at 2013-11-18 07:43" as we see from the command line but unfortunately job is not executing..as the php script is supposed to create a text file which is working fine with command line(using Putty) and obviously I am getting no mail in my ec2-user mail folder

Comment: Has php proper permissions to write that file?

Comment: yeah, but not when executed via the web server?

Comment: Php file has proper permission to write a file..when I call that file from my browser it does write that file

Comment: why should the curl call store a file?

Comment: with curl I am calling to timetest.php file...which is creating a text file

Comment: ah, understand. have no further ideas. If you doing it all right, it should work.

Comment: is there something related to permission..I am completely unaware of it..because when I send command from command line(Putty)..it goes as "ec2-user" user..and when command is executed via web then who is user????

Comment: Depends on your OS.. Try `passthru('whoami');`