# PHP Add scheduled task in Linux "PAM failure System error"

Tags: php, cron, scheduled-tasks

Im running this code in my php file:

```
shell_exec('echo wget http://192.168.20.1:8080/proj/add_user/ | at -t 201606281053');
```

in my var/log/httpd/error_log, it says "PAM failure System error".

I'm trying to add a scheduled task in my server but this doesn't seem to work.

I refer to this thread but no success.
[how to pass arguments to linux at command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980131/how-to-pass-arguments-to-linux-at-command)

Thank You!

Comment: Well, most likely you have to authorize the `sudo` call. That won't work without an interactive TTY. That is why PAM fails. What you could do is to "white list" the specific call in `/etc/sudoers`, so that you can execute that call _without_ getting asked for the root password.

Comment: I added "apache    ALL=(ALL)" NOPASSWD:ALL" and restarted the system but still no luck

Comment: It might be that your `PATH` environment variables differ. So use the absolute paths to the two executables `wget` and `at` (`echo` usually is a shell builtin command).